# Redeclare Queue on Network issues or RabbitMQ restart

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-camel, amqp

I have a setup where RabbitMQ queue is set to 'auto-delete'. There are situations where RabbitMQ consumer app can lose its connection / channel to RMQ server because of

- networking issue
- RabbitMQ server has been restarted

In both situations, there is a high possibility that the queue may be deleted by RabbitMQ as there are no active consumers.

It would be good when the connection is reestablished and if 'declare' is true on 'rabbitmq component', the queue is redeclared. Otherwise even though connection is reestablished the queue is not created.

Workaround but not preferred
- background thread to ensure queue is always there. so when client reestablishes connection, the messages flow to consuming app

Possible implementation change to `rabbitmq-component`
- extend `org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitConsumer` to reconnect plus declare queue on `handleShutdownSignal`
or
- RabbitConsumer to notify external listeners to perform some work (redeclare queue) on channel shutdown

apart from the above, please let know if there are any reasonable workaround(s) without modifying `camel-rabbitmq` component?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually want the queue to be deleted in the first place. Why not just not delete it automatically?

Comment: it is a reasonable requirement to be deleted so that microservices using queues can come and disappear and no manual intervention involved for cleanup.

Comment: @Rag any solution you found for this? I have similar situation when a queue will not be allowed to redeclare.